# App Crashes When try to retrieve contact without profile from phonebook

Tags: android

i have a fab button. on clicking it will open our phone book, there we can select a contact and it will be shown in our app in `RecyclerView` . I'm fetching contacts id,name,photo,number.

**Works fine** -- when i retrieve contact who has a photo in phonebook

**Error comes** -- when i retrieve contact without a photo the App crashses with a msg App stopped working

Help me guyz,thnx in advance

```
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ImportantContact extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = ImportantContact.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS = 1;
private Uri uriContact;
private String contactID;     // contacts unique ID
Bitmap photo;
String contactNumber;
String contactName;

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
List<ImportantPeopleDataset> list = new ArrayList<>();
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.important_contact);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.imp_contacts_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //list.add(new ImportantPeopleDataset("Dinesh", "8889731492", R.drawable.bharat));

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.nav_imp_contacts_recyclerview);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    //mLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new MyImportantContactAdapter(list);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();


            onClickSelectContact(view); //App crashes when a contact without pic is selected

        }
    });

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public void onClickSelectContact(View btnSelectContact) {

    // using native contacts selection
    // Intent.ACTION_PICK = Pick an item from the data, returning what was selected.
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + data.toString());
        uriContact = data.getData();

        retrieveContactName();
        retrieveContactNumber();
        retrieveContactPhoto();

    }
}

private void retrieveContactPhoto() {

    photo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
            R.drawable.bharat);

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(contactID)));

        if (inputStream != null) {
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_contact);
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }

        assert inputStream != null;
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    list.add(new ImportantPeopleDataset(contactName, contactNumber, photo));

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//notify item remove b hota h remove krte tume use kr lena

}

private void retrieveContactNumber() {

    contactNumber = null;

    // getting contacts ID
    Cursor cursorID = getContentResolver().query(uriContact,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
            null, null, null);

    if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {

        contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    }

    cursorID.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Contact ID: " + contactID);

    // Using the contact ID now we will get contact phone number
    Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

            new String[]{contactID},
            null);

    if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
        contactNumber = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)).trim().replace(" ", "");
    }                                                                                      //.trim().replace(" ","") is used for removing extra space in phone number

    cursorPhone.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Contact Phone Number: " + contactNumber);
}

private void retrieveContactName() {

    contactName = null;

    // querying contact data store
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriContact, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        // DISPLAY_NAME = The display name for the contact.
        // HAS_PHONE_NUMBER =   An indicator of whether this contact has at least one phone number.

        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }

    cursor.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Contact Name: " + contactName);

}


}
```

**important_contact.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/imp_contacts_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_imp_contacts_recyclerview"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MyImportantContactAdapter.java**

```
package com.bharat.fcr;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

/**
 * Created by Dinesh on 3/25/2016.
 */
public class MyImportantContactAdapter extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<MyImportantContactAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    List<ImportantPeopleDataset> list = Collections.emptyList();

    public MyImportantContactAdapter(List<ImportantPeopleDataset> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_important_contacts, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
      holder.number.setText(list.get(position).getNumber());
           holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());

        holder.pic.setImageBitmap(list.get(position).getBmp());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list != null ? list.size() : 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name, number;
        CircleImageView pic;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_imp_contacts_name);
            number = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_imp_contacts_number);
            pic = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_imp_contacts_profile);
        }
    }
}
```

**cardview_important_contacts.xml   --No cardview used ignore name format**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView

    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardview_imp_contacts_profile"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bharat"/>
    <TextView
android:textColor="#4b3e3e"
        android:id="@+id/cardview_imp_contacts_name"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Name"
        />
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#4b3e3e"
        android:id="@+id/cardview_imp_contacts_number"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Pnone Number"
        />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```